# SessionFactory init failed with spring and hibernate 5.2.5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I'm trying to update a Spring application to use the 5.2 version of Hibernate Core in order to use the Java 8 Date/Time Types. in my POM, I am using the `4.3.4.RELEASE` for Spring dependencies and `5.2.5.Final` for Hibernate. I have also changed the the packages to hibernate5 in the `HibernateConfiguration`

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
```

Here is the exception being thrown:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/moor/dummyservice/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:511)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
    ... 70 more
```

Is there anything else to be configured in order to get it working together?

Comment: Seeing your `HibernateConfiguration` might be helpful in diagnosing this.

Answer (score 0):

it turned out to be a runtime dependency mismatch, since I'm using Jarida Money, it has some transitive dependencies to `hibernate-entitymanager`

```
[INFO] +- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:jar:5.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
```

This is the configuration that works for me:

```
<properties>
    <springframework.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <jackson.version>2.5.3</jackson.version>
    <springsecurity.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    <springsecurityoauth2.version>2.0.10.RELEASE</springsecurityoauth2.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.5.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet & JEE stuff -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security OAuth2-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurityoauth2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.spi</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-money</artifactId>
        <version>0.12</version>
    </dependency>
```